# How to check if a number is in certain range?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
if(answer1 == 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
{
    answer2 = 1;
}

if(answer1 != 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
{
    answer1 = 1;
}
```

That is coming up with an error so how do a check different numbers without having 10 if statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are dealing with int values and you have to check with a range of numbers i.e 2-10 in your case, you can use <= or >=  operators. Like in this particular case:

```
if(answer1 >= 2 && answer1 <= 10)
{
    answer2 = 1;
}
else
{
    answer1 = 1;
}
```